# Numbers are very small in numerator and denominator using \frac

Tags: math-mode, fractions

When I use the `\frac` command, I notice that the characters used for the fraction terms become smaller than those which are not in the `\frac` command. Is there a way to correct it?

Comment: Well, this is normal, isn't it? That is 1.5 shouldn't appear as 11/2 and the standard formatting uses a smaller 1 and 2 for the 1/2 precisely to show that they are the numerator and denominator.

Comment: There is a reason: a big fraction in text will spread lines apart and that's bad. Prefer the slashed form for inline fractions: `$1/2$` instead of `$\frac{1}{2}$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A larger (nicer?) version of the fraction can be obtained with `\dfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}



\begin{align}
\gamma &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} \\
 & \notag \\
\gamma &= \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-\dfrac{v^2}{c^2}}}
\end{align}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but *please* don't use this form in text, only in display.

Comment: thank you very much Barbara , and why is that ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: The OP did not mention text mode ...

Comment: true, but the op didn't specify display mode either.  it makes a difference.  actually, while i agree totally with using `\dfrac` for the "outer" one in your example, i think using it within the root is too much.  the "intermediate" size (mentioned in another comment) is a good option here.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: that's true too, but I had no impression that inline fractions are used. I used an `align` environment for true math, not inline, otherwise `nicefrac` or `xfrac` are the right choice

Answer (score 4):

For fractions, `nicefrac` may be preferred. Here's a comparison:

[image: fractional]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nicefrac}

\begin{document}
  This is some text with a $\frac{1}{2}$ in it.

  This is some text with a \textonehalf{} in it.

  This is some text with a \nicefrac{1}{2} in it.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution would be to use medium-sized fractions (~ 80% of displaystyle, defined in `nccmath`), plus a slight increase of `\baselineskip` with `setstretch`. For large operators, there is a `\medop` command:

```
\documentclass{article}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.1}

\begin{document}

This is some text without fractions.

This is some text without fractions. This is some text without fractions. 

  This is some text with a $\mfrac{1}{2}$ in it: $ p(x,y) = \medop\sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \medop\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{mn} \sin \bigl(\mfrac{m \pi x}{a}\bigr) \sin \bigl(\mfrac{n \pi y}{b}\bigr) $

This is again some text without fractions. Again some text without fractions.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is one problem , if i use dfrac in this formula , some characters are small , some are big : 

$ p(x,y) = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_{mn} sin (\dfrac{m \pi x}{a}) sin (\dfrac{n \pi y}{b}) $

Comment: You shouldn't use `\dfrac` for in-line formulae, unless you accept the interline skips be unequal! Note it is possible to obtain medium-sized operators like `\sum`, `\prod`, &c. See my updated answer. Btw, if you want to type the sine function, and not the product of 3 variables `s, i, n`, you should type `\sin` with a backslash.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\dfrac` for larger fractions with bigger numbers. `\dfrac` belongs to the `amsmath` package, so you will need to import that. Also, the reason why it is called dfrac is because it is a `\frac` that is in display mode, which in general makes things larger.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Large Fraction: $\dfrac{1}{2}$
Small Fraction: $\frac{1}{2}$
\end{document}
```

[image: compiled source]

BTW, if you want to do a fraction like "1/2" (with the slash) use `\sfrac`

Comment: This is already covered, in detail, by all the other answers.